# How to reference the right scope with CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I am confused about how to reference the outer scope from an inner scope in this case:

```
that = @
@collection.bind 'reset', ->
  that.render()
```

Is there any CoffeeScript construct that makes the `that = @` look better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, this is what the [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) is for:

```
@collection.bind 'reset', =>
  @render()
```

It compiles into:

```
var _this = this;

this.collection.bind('reset', function() {
  return _this.render();
});
```